# How can I connect with each of the computer component with hyper terminal?

Tags: windows, hyperterminal

I just come to know the existence of this tool:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows NT\hypertrm.exe"
```

I'm curious how I can use it to connect to the hard-disk,cpu,camera,etc..

Anyone knows?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperterminal

Answer (score 1):

HyperTerminal is a program that's been around since Widows 95.  It's used to communicate to modems and other serial (COM) devices.  It cannot 'connect' to hard drives, CPUs, or similar.  And even if it could, what exactly would you do with it?

Comment: Perhaps the same sort of thing that this person (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXmv8quf_xM) is using tracert for.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what hyperterminal is for. It's used to log into remote machines, basically a graphical "telnet" program.

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can **log into a remote machine** with the hyperterminal??

Comment: HyperTerminal is obsolete junk. If you need to log into a remote machine, get something like PuTTY (google for "putty.exe").

Comment: I'm interested how hyperterminal can be used as a graphical telnet,how can I use it to do something like `telnet localhost 80`?